# I need to place a jQuery value or variable inside plugin options

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins, revolution-slider

I need to place a jQuery value or variable inside plugin options

My script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // var bannerheight =  580;
    if ($(window).width() < 2100) {
      var bannerheight =  410;

      var opts = JSON.parse($('#revolutionSlider').attr('data-plugin-options'));
      opts.startheight = bannerheight; alert(opts.startheight);

      $('#revolutionSlider').attr('data-plugin-options', JSON.stringify(opts));
  }
});

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="revolutionSlider" style="background:grey;" data-plugin-options='{"startheight": 430}' data-plugin-revolution-slider></div>
```

I need to place the banner value that i got from jQuery script inside `data-plugin-options='{"startheight": 430}'`. That is instead of value "430" I need value from jQuery script

Answer (score 1):

You will need to:

1. Parse the options JSON to a JS object
2. Change the value
3. Serialize the object to JSON
4. Set the JSON as attribute value.

The following should work. Do it after you calculate `bannerheight`.

```
var opts = JSON.parse($('#revolutionSlider').attr('data-plugin-options'));
opts.startheight = bannerheight;
$('#revolutionSlider').attr('data-plugin-options', JSON.stringify(opts));
```

Comment: not working. this is what i have done `if ($(window).width() < 1600) {
      var bannerheight =  410;
   var opts = JSON.parse($('#revolutionSlider').attr('data-plugin-options'));
opts.startheight = bannerheight;
$('#revolutionSlider').attr('data-plugin-options', JSON.stringify(opts));
}`

Comment: @YadhuBabu -- when you say _not working_, it is hard to judge what exactly isn't working. You don't have a working example in the question, which can be used to replicate the problem. The code I've posted is syntactically correct and should work as per your question. So next time when you say something isn't working, do include the details of how did you try running it, what exactly is the issue and most importantly, create a verifiable example.

Comment: I have edited my question as per your suggestion. when i am alerting `opts.startheight` getting value. but the height is not changing

Comment: @YadhuBabu -- Did you observe the generated HTML? The height changes successfully. Observe that using your browser's developer tools.

Comment: Yeh I can see that. But it is not working in my website. One more doubt can I covert `opts.startheight` to a php variable

Answer (score 1):

This could be hackish way but works

1.get the current value
2. Change the value and set again

```
let raw_rev_options = jQuery('#revolutionSlider').attr('data-plugin-options');
let rev_options = JSON.parse(raw_rev_options);
rev_options.startheight = bannerheight;
jQuery('#revolutionSlider').attr('data-plugin-options', JSON.stringify(rev_options));
```

Comment: no working. `alert(console.log(rev_options.startheight)); ` shows undefined

Comment: remove console.log from the alert , it should be `alert(rev_options.startheight);`

Comment: I have updated my question with your code please check

Comment: i think your revslider ui changes are not happening thats because you should not change the dom content. you should use functions of revolutionSlider to change its height.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177330/discussion-between-yadhu-babu-and-thamaraiselvam).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your script after your else condition and check if this works.

```
$("#revolutionSlider").attr('data-plugin-options',"{'startheight':"+bannerheight+" }");
```

Comment: currently Im using that value as 430 `data-plugin-options='{"startheight": 430}` should i keep it empty